# How to I find an element with protractor?

Tags: protractor, saucelabs

It seems if I use `element(by.css('#id'));` protractor sometimes finds it, sometimes doesn't. Depends if the DOM is settled down or not. I've gone and some this:

```
getElementsByCss: function (cssVal) {
  // return element.all((by.css(cssVal)));
  return self.wait(function () {
    return element.all((by.css(cssVal))).then(function (els) {
      return els;
    }, function () {
      return false; // Don't fail, we want to retry
    });
  }, GET_ELEMENT_TIMEOUT, 'Elements not found by css: '  + cssVal);
},
```

which plays a game of retrying to get the element for some timeout period. We use 5 seconds. This seems to work, most of the time. When running locally we have no issues.

When we run on the cloud (sauce labs) they have exceedingly slow VMs. We still get random issues. Unfortunately these games have to be played everywhere, for example:

```
getText: function (el) {
  return self.wait(function () {
    return el.getText();
  }, 1000, 'Could not get element text.');
},
```

or

```
expectBulletin: function () {
  var el, text;
  return self.wait(function () {
      // Find the bulleting element, make sure it's visible and grab its text.
      // If any of those three fail, try all of them again.
      return self.getElementByCss('.bulletin')
        .then(function (elm) {
          el = elm;
          return self.isElementVisible(el);
        }, function () {
          return false;
        })
        .then(function () {
          return self.getText(el).then(function (text) {
            return text;
          }, function () {
            return false;
          });
        }, function () {
          return false;
        });
    }, 10000, 'Count not get bulletin text.')
    .then(function (result) {
      text = result;
      return self.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', el.getWebElement());
    })
    .then(function () {
      return self.isElementNotVisible(el);
    })
    .then(function () {
      return text;
    });
},
```

all the `self.wait`s are just a browser.driver.wait wrapper...

```
wait: function (fn, timeout, msg) {
  return browser.driver.wait(fn, timeout, msg);
},
```

This feels like a big pack of bandaids and its not working all the time. `expectBulletin` works 99% of the time locally, but when run remotely on the slow VMs, it works about 50% of the time. Sometimes the text comes back blank, or issues about clicking an invisible element or just not finding the bulletin element.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Sometimes we really feel the same way about the remote tests we have - it's a lot of waits upon waits under waits and expected conditions. I am afraid you have to go this way if you want your tests to be reliable. Here is a bit crazy idea, but can probably have an impact, try it out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27483971/771848. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems if I use element(by.css('#id')); protractor sometimes finds
>   it, sometimes doesn't.

You know that it returns a promise right? If you want to get the absolute value of an element, you have to handle its promise first.

Protractor waits for the page to be ready before doing any assertions. If your page is "ready" but some data is missing, there is something wrong with your angular application.