# protractor sendKeys sends keys in the wrong order

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I am trying to test some form by adding appropriate text to my input fields, but for some reason I am not getting what I'm sending. The problem I am having is with `['name=type_input]'` and `sendKeys('Ciężarówka')`. When I run the test the input field gets filled with letters in the wrong order, for example "kaCiężaów" or "aCiężarówk" and that causes my entire test to fail. Sometimes the order is correct and than the test passes. Can someone explain what is happening?

```
it('should add vehicle', function() {
   element(by.css('[name=type_input]')).sendKeys('Ciężarówka').sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);

   element(by.css('[name=name]')).sendKeys('Nie Super Auto 555').sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
   element(by.model('model.carId')).sendKeys('54536');
   element(by.css('[name=numberPlate]')).sendKeys('KU PAA').sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
   helpers.selectAnyFromKendoComboBox('vehicle', 'haulier');
   helpers.save('vehicle');

   alertify.expectSuccessMessage('Zapisano');

});
```

Comment: Are you using chrome for tests?

Comment: Yes. I'm using chrome

Comment: There are some known bug about `ChromeDriver` for `sendKeys()`. ATM I haven't find anything related, but I think you should do a try with another browser, to check if it's a chrome bug

Comment: If it is, a possible workaround is here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2019#issuecomment-184667893

Comment: Also curious if special characters are the cause?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *isolate the problem*:

- is this `input` the only one with this behavior in your application? Does it have an input validation or any animations related to typing?
- would the test fail if you would type, say, `test` instead of `Ciężarówka`?
- can you reproduce the problem in other browsers or other machines?

---

Here is a couple of things to try:

- [use "slow typing"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38187514/771848). This helped me couple of times to make the typing work reliably across all the target browsers.
- [disable all Angular animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584451/how-to-disable-animations-in-protractor-for-angular-js-application)

Comment: That is the only input that is giving me a problem. Other types of vehicles are "Naczepa", "Przyczepa" and "Ciągnik". They all pass the test. I thought that the problem is related to Polish letters ą, ę, ó etc. since there is so many of them in "Ciężarówka" , but in a word "Ciągnik" there is a letter "ą" and protractor doesn't have a problem with it.

Comment: No validation or animation. Still have to check it on other browsers

Comment: I've run same tests muliple times on different machine, where internet connection is much slower and all the tests passed? Any ideas how to fix this so I don't have this problem on the machine I usually work. I like the idea of "slow typing" but when I was trying to implement it in my code I received an error saying ".sleep is not a function"

Comment: @LukaszKisicki yeah, cause you need to introduce the `sleep` action. There is a note about that in the linked topic. Thanks.