# How to reduce speed of e2e test in angular2 using protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, e2e-testing, angular2-testing

I am running e2e test cases for angular2 app using protractor.

So far my tests are getting compiled & results are generated.

But I cant see whats happening on browser as operations are quite fast.

I want to know how to reduce the speed of these test cases so I will be able to track the form data & other things correctly.

If I can add delay then how to do it?

thanks

Comment: use breakpoint and/or `debugger` in your code?

Comment: @Endless how? could you add a small snippet or something?

Comment: Have a look at the doc: http://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27483971/3637106

Answer (score 0):

pauses the script, need to have console opend

```js
document.body.innerHTML = 20;
var x = 15 * 5;
debugger;
document.body.innerHTML = x;
```